# Powershell backup script creating directory

Tags: powershell

I have this type of code in a backup script.

```
while($true){
$time = Get-Date -Format HH:mm:ss
$dateCheck = (Get-Date).AddDays(-0).ToString('dd-MM-yyyy')
[int]$check = $check


Get-ChildItem 'C:\fleet-integrator-installer-DHL2\work\matilda\14\done' -File |
Sort-Object -Property CreationTime -Descending |
Select-Object -First 1 |
Copy-Item -Destination \\Ict_nas\dhl\$dateCheck -Force

if($time -eq ('23:59:00')){
$check = $check - $check
}

if($time -eq ('23:59:30') -and $check -eq 0){
New-Item -ItemType "directory" -Path "\\Ict_nas\dhl" -Name $dateCheck | Out-Null
$check++
}

if($time -eq ('00:00:00')){
$fileCount = ( Get-ChildItem C:\fleet-integrator-installer-DHL2\work\matilda\14\done ).Count;
$EmailFrom = "..."
$EmailTo = "..."
$Subject = "Backup DHL Integrator -> IT NAS"
$Body = "The backup was succesful, $fileCount files are copied to the NAS"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("", "")
$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\fleet-integrator-installer-DHL2\work\matilda\14\done -Include *.* -File -Recurse | foreach { $_.Delete()}
}




}
```

It is creating automaticly an folder with the date of today on a NAS.

When i run the code separate it is working fine but in the script it is just creating a file with the date of today...

Anyone tips?

Thanks

Comment: Does `md` instead of `New-Item` work??

Comment: Will try, because if i run that part of the script in a new tab it is working fine...

Answer (score 0):

You are copying to the directory before creating it:

```
Copy-Item -Destination \\Ict_nas\dhl\$dateCheck -Force
```

Because the directory does not exist (yet), the destination is interpreted as a file name. So the source file is copied to a file of that name.

I am not sure what your `$check` logic is supposed to do, but basically you have 2 options:

**A)** Create the directory first, *before* copying to it

```
New-Item "\\Ict_nas\dhl\$dateCheck" -Type Directory | Out-Null
Get-ChildItem 'C:\fleet-integrator-installer-DHL2\work\matilda\14\done' -File |
  sort CreationTime -Descending | select -First 1 |
  Copy-Item \\Ict_nas\dhl\$dateCheck
```

**B)** Specify a *full* file path for copying

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\fleet-integrator-installer-DHL2\work\matilda\14\done' -File |
sort CreationTime -Descending | select -First 1 | foreach {
    Copy-Item $_.FullName "\\Ict_nas\dhl\$dateCheck\$($_.Name)"
}
```